# What is rate node_context_switches_total and why rate(node_context_switches_total[5m]) > 1000?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus-node-exporter

I've set up prometheus on my cluster with a couple of alert rules like this one :

```yaml
 - alert: ContextSwitching
   expr: rate(node_context_switches_total[5m]) > 1000
   for: 30m
   labels:
   severity: warning
```

Can someone shed some light on the purpose of this rule?

Also, in my case `rate(node_context_switches_total[5m])` is always greater than 2000. Is that something I should be worried about ?

Answer (score 0):

A context switch is the action of storing the state of a process or of a thread.
As per [Prometheus Documentation book](http://file.allitebooks.com/20190512/Prometheus%20Up%20%20Running.pdf) and [metrics description](https://docs.signalfx.com/en/latest/integrations/agent/monitors/prometheus-node.html) -

`node_context_switches_total` is Total number of context switches.

Typical alert looks like:

```
  - alert: ContextSwitching
    expr: rate(node_context_switches_total[5m]) > 1000
    for: 30m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: "Context switching (instance {{ $labels.instance }})"
      description: "Context switching is growing on node (> 1000 / s)\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"
```